# Which regex to use in R?

Tags: regex, r

Does anybody know which regex to use to extract this character `stddata__2015_02_04` from this character `"<li><a href=\"stddata__2015_02_04/\"> stddata__2015_02_04/</a></li>"` in R? You may assume that the begging `stddata__201` is known, and only the ending changes from time to time.

Comment: [Quote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3521006): "HTML is a language of sufficient complexity that it cannot be parsed by regular expressions. _Even Jon Skeet cannot parse HTML using regular expressions_. Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp." [italics added]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input is:

```
x <- "<li><a href=\"stddata__2015_02_04/\"> stddata__2015_02_04/</a></li>"
```

then use `sub`:

```
sub(".*(stddata__201[_0-9]+).*", "\\1", x)
```

giving:

```
[1] "stddata__2015_02_04"
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression:

```
.*(stddata__201[_0-9]+).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Y-fWMAUvUISY-AoO)

Answer (score 2):

I tend to agree with the other posters, Regex is not the best way to do this. However, if you REALLY want to do this with Regex, here it goes.

```
(?<=>\s)([^<>\/])+        # Works in php and python, and most other languages
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> library("stringr")
> str_extract("<li><a href=\"stddata__2015_02_04/\"> stddata__2015_02_04/</a></li>",
+             "stddata__201[0-9]_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}")
[1] "stddata__2015_02_04"
```

preferred solution is not to regex...

```
> library("rvest")
> "<li><a href=\"stddata__2015_02_04/\"> stddata__2015_02_04/</a></li>" %>% 
+   html() %>% 
+   html_text()
[1] " stddata__2015_02_04/"
```

Comment: Thanks. 
The same operation works in stringi package
stri_extract()
but is faster :)

Comment: oooh! the rvest package looks better :) ! great solution